# Mapping touch screen and wacom tablet to different monitors under wayland using libinput

Tags: wayland, libinput, wacom

I have recently switched to wayland, and running sway on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm trying to map my touch screen and wacom tablet to specific monitors. I have 3 monitors connected and working properly. I have been reading the `libinput` documentation without being able to find a solution. The PC recognizes the devices, and they work, however, they are mapped to all the available area. I tried using `xinput map-to-output` however it displays a warning message and then gives an error:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
Unable to find output 'eDP-1'. Output may not be connected.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can't help much here, but to give you some pointers: on Wayland you need to do configuration through your compositor. `xinput` in particular not gonna work here, which is what the message is trying to say you. You gotta research configuration available to your Wayland compositor, and if there doesn't seem to be any way to do that, report a feature request to them
.

Comment: This is actually helpful. If I understand what you're saying correctly, the monitor setup is done via compositor, that I agree. I use `libinput` to read configuration, I can also use the simple setup using `xinput set-prop`. That's why I wonder if there would be a workaround. In the mean time, I will submit a feature request. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer here:
https://man.archlinux.org/man/sway-input.5

Adding this to config solves the problem

```
input <input_device_identifier> map_to_output <output_device_identifier>
```