# How to calibrate touch screen on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: wayland, touch-screen, multi-touch

We have a box connecting to a 20" vertical touch screen.  When running Ubuntu 20.04 which runs X.org we used xinput_calibrator to calibrate the touch screen since it is vertical.  However in Ubuntu 22.04 it by default runs Xwayland (which we found a much better performance running vnc).  We couldn't use xinput_calibrator to do that.

I've tried to find some information. This one:

[Mapping touch screen and wacom tablet to different monitors under wayland using libinput](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663158/mapping-touch-screen-and-wacom-tablet-to-different-monitors-under-wayland-using)

is using sway.  However ubuntu 22.04 by default seems to use mutter as window manager.

How can I do calibration like xinput_calibrator in 22.04 (Xwayland, mutter)?